# how to access RFH2/usr folder from WMQ using JMS API

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have a Java JMS application that reads messages from a MQ queue. My application can successfully read a message and pull out the JMS headers (e.g. JMSDeliveryMode, JMSPriority etc) and the message body, but I can not access the `<usr>` folder part of the message.

I am placing messages on a queue using RFHutil. Under the RFH tab I am ticking 'Include RFH V2 Headers' and 'usr', and under the usr tab I have test1=1. I can see the `<usr><test1>1</test1></usr>` in the message if I browse the queue using MQExplorer, so I think I'm setting the usr folder correctly.

I have outputted the whole of `message.getPropertyNames()` enumeration (as discussed at topic [JMS passing entire Application data <usr> block](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=48300), but my usr fields are not under there. My message body also does not contain my usr fields.

I've also read on the MQ v7 info center you need to set WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY to WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ, but I am using v6MQ and do not know if this is relevant/how to set this value.

How can I get access to the usr folder using the JMS API?

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated as I am fairly new to JMS programming.

Comment: If receiver knows the name of user property, he can get the value with the method like getStringProperty(): https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getStringProperty%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score -1):

A first question is why is the USR folder of importance?  Are you attempting to get your JMS application to interoperate with messages that put using another application that writes custom RFH2 headers.

RFHUtil is primarily used for test purposes.

MQ JMS originally used the RFH2 heasder to specifically send the JMS properties. Therefore the MQ JMS code reads the message, removes the RFH2 and processes it into a full JMS Message.

If you want the JMS API to fully read the RFH2, then the properties for reading the MQ message you've highlighted are correct. However those are not in MQ v6. Be aware that mq v6 and V7.0.1 are now out of support. Would strongly recommend that you investigate upgrading to MQ v8 - at minimum MQ 7.5.

CLients are freely downloadable if you are a developer and connecting to an estbalished QueueManager. Client versions don't have to match the QM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lets forget about RFHUtil at this time.My actual scenario is As source team keeps the routing info in RFH2 header. So, i need to get that info using JMS API. First please suggest Is there any chance to access RFH2Header or JMS protocol doesn't accept the RFH2 Header. And i am using MQ 7.5.